# Using aquamacs and emacs on the same box

Tags: macos, emacs, aquamacs

I have `aquamacs` installed and running nicely on my OS X. I wanted to have, in addition a standard `emacs` which I downloaded and installed. As I expected they share the same `.emacs` file, which is fine - I would like the two to have the same features.

When I run the emacs in debug mode, I get an error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file"
"org-install"$   require(org-install)
```

which is related to the `org-mode` I have and want to use. In my `.emacs` file I have:

```
(require 'org-install)
```

which is the line which causes the problem. `locate org-install` yielded several locations, some are in `/Applications/Aquamacs.app/`, and thus maybe invisible to `emacs`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What version of emacs is Aquamacs using? What version of standard `emacs` are you using? Using different versions often causes some of the problems that you're experiencing. I experienced some of this myself when I mixed emacs version (using Emacs.app [downloaded] and the builtin emacs).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Emacs 24 (in pretest) then `org-mode` is included and you shouldn't be having any problems.  Otherwise you will have to [install it](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html).  I suppose that you could just add the path to `org-mode` which is included with Aquamacs to the variable `load-path`.  This might work, but there may be problems with the byte-compiled files being for a different version etc.  You can also install `org-mode` from [ELPA](http://tromey.com/elpa/).